# Adding zoom to extent button to layers displayed in ol-ext LayerSwitcher in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, layer-switcher, ol-ext

I need a LayerSwitcher with the possibility of including a "zoom to extent" button for each layer. So, searching I found the example:

https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/control/map.switcher.html

I took the source code of the example and made a change, including another layer `layer_limit`. However, this layer that includes it did not show the "zoom to extent" button, as it is on
`GEOLOGIE` layer. Can someone help me?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var brgm = new ol.layer.Tile ({
"title": "GEOLOGIE",
"extent": [
  -653182.6969582437,
  5037463.842847037,
  1233297.5065495989,
  6646432.677299531
],
"minResolution": 3.527777777777778,
"maxResolution": 3527.777777777778,
"source": new ol.source.TileWMS({
  "url": "https://geoservices.brgm.fr/geologie",
  "projection": "EPSG:3857",
  "params": {
    "LAYERS": "GEOLOGIE",
    "FORMAT": "image/png",
    "VERSION": "1.3.0"
  },
  "attributions": [
    "<a href='http://www.brgm.fr/'>&copy; Brgm</a>"
  ]
})
});
  
var layer_limit = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Limit',
    visible: true,
    zIndex: 1,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(83,0,255,0.050980392156862744)',
        opacity: 1
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)',
        width: 4,
        opacity: 1
      })
    }),
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=LIM&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
              'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});
// The Map
var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',  
 view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-46.444137, -23.713596]), 
        zoom: 12
    }),
layers: [ baseLayers, brgm, layer_limit ]
});

map.addControl(new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({ 
//target:$(".layerSwitcher").get(0), 
//trash: true, 
extent: true,
collapsed: false 
}));
```

Comment: Zoom to extent button is shown for those layers that have extent defined. Layer `brgm` has extent, but layer `layer_limit` doesn't.

Comment: How can I set the extension when creating the `layer_limit` layer, the way it is being created? I can't leave it fixed, as it is constantly being added to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zoom to extent button is shown for those layers that have extent defined. Layer `brgm` has extent, but layer `layer_limit` doesn't.

One possible solution for this is to catch `featuresloadend` event for `layer_limit` layer source, get source extent, then set `layer_limit` extent and only then add layer switcher control.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var layer_switcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({ 
  extent: true,
  collapsed: false 
});

var layer_limit_source = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent) {
    return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
      'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=LIM&' +
      'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
      'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
})
layer_limit_source.on('featuresloadend', function(evt) {
  var extent = layer_limit_source.getExtent();
  layer_limit.setExtent(extent);
  map.addControl(layer_switcher);
});

var layer_limit = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: 'Limit',
  visible: true,
  zIndex: 1,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(83,0,255,0.050980392156862744)',
      opacity: 1
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)',
      width: 4,
      opacity: 1
    })
  }),
  source: layer_limit_source
});
```

Comment: Got it, thank you. In the example I only used one layer `layer_limit`, but if there are more layers, where should I add `map.addControl(layer_switcher);`?

Comment: If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved. If there are more layers, add layer switcher when all are loaded. If you don't know how to do that, that's a separate question, otherwise one question could go ad infinitum.